# Removing a directory that has no files in it

Tags: command-line, directory, ls, rm

I recently created a username and a group called `gamesForAdmin`. Since then I deleted it and the folder I made for it is still there:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root       4096 Jul  4 11:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root       4096 May 29 12:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 sftpuser sftpaccess 4096 Jul  4 11:24 gamesForAdmin
drwxr-xr-x 27 ryan     ryan       4096 Jul  4 11:31 ryan
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     sftpaccess 4096 Jul  4 11:29 sftpuser
```

When I try to run a `sudo rmdir gamesForAdmin`, I get this error message:

```
rmdir: failed to remove ‘gamesForAdmin’: Directory not empty
```

But theres nothing in the directory! When I run an `ls`, there is nothing listed.

- Why does this occur?
- How I can successfully remove this directory?

Output of `ls -la gamesForAdmin`:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 sftpuser sftpaccess 4096 Jul  4 11:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root       4096 Jul  4 11:28 ..
-rw------- 1 sftpuser sftpaccess  471 Jun  9 19:49 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 sftpuser sftpaccess  220 Apr  8 21:03 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 sftpuser sftpaccess 3637 Apr  8 21:03 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 sftpuser sftpaccess  675 Apr  8 21:03 .profile
-rw------- 1 sftpuser sftpaccess  644 Jun  9 17:48 .viminfo
```

Comment: For the record, you can also use `rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty`, but of course that's longer than `rm -rf` and no sane person would ever use it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the output you're showing in your question the directory `gamesForAdmin` is not empty, so `rmdir` cannot remove this directory. To remove it you'll need to use `rm -fr` instead. Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf gamesForAdmin
```

which should fix you right up.

Comment: you've very welcome

Comment: probably don't need the `f`.

Comment: better safe than trying again

Answer (score 6):

Your folder can have some hidden files (`ls` doesn't show [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) by default, i.e. files whose name begins with `.` are hidden).

Run:

```
ls -la gamesForAdmin
```

to check if there is any hidden files in it.

**Updated**

According to your result `ls -la`, your directory is not empty, so `rmdir` can not remove it, `rmdir` only work with empty directory.

To remove it, you can use:

```
rm -r gamesForAdmin
```

Comment: Good point :), I will put the results in my question

Answer (score 2):

`ls -al` is great for checking to see if there are any hidden directories.

Barring that `rm -rf` removes recursively and forces the removal, keep in mind that `rm -rf \` will delete everything. Depending on distro this may throw an error, or demo your entire file system.

Ubuntu normally doesn't let you do an rm to your root filesystem.